# sudo and apt-get not found

Tags: server, apt, sudo

I'm handling server as RA which was passed down to me by another graduated RA but I'm new and fresh to this environment facing a few issues right now. The server is setup by the graduate RA from scratch.

First of all, I'm accessing the server via PuTTY and logging in the server with `username:root` and its password. Then I'm trying to run some command but it shows `sudo: not found`.
NOTE:username is ROOT. NOT THE ROOT PRIVILLEGE.

I tried surfing for solution which asked me to install `sudo` with `apt-get install sudo` but `apt-get: not found` popped out.

Since I'm accessing via PuTTY, I'm not able to get into grub menu for root shell prompt. I did a reboot but it didn't help.

Please help me on this issue, I highly appreciate all solutions.

Comment: Are you supposed to be in sudoers group ? can you use `su` to login as root ?

Comment: Login via root. At the /etc directory, I do not see sudoers file but shadow and gshadow.

Comment: If you're logging in with root user... Why you're prepending `sudo` to commands?

Comment: But I'm always getting such response.
~ # ftp google.com
~ ash : ftp : not found
~ # apt-get install update
~ ash : apt-get : not found

Comment: Hello, I just found out that username is ROOT. NOT THE ROOT PRIVILLEGE.

Comment: Can you give us the output of `uname -a`? It should tell us something about the distribution you're using. Also, if you could give us the output of `id` to get some more info on your user, that would help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not using Ubuntu, it certainly doesn't sounds like it anyway. Please check the output of `cat /etc/os-release`. If it isn't Ubuntu, please delete this question (we only deal with Ubuntu here) and ask on [unix.se] instead.

Answer (score 1):

The whole purpose of `sudo` is to temporarily allow you to do what `root` can do.

If another person has been putting it together from scratch, it is highly probable that person got rid of `sudo`. As long as you can use root account, you can do everything you need.

Comment: This isn't a complete answer, he asked for `apt-get` too.

Comment: Hello sir. I'm getting this error as well. But I'm always getting such response.
~ # ftp google.com
~ ash : ftp : not found
~ # apt-get install update
~ ash : apt-get : not found

Comment: @ZDroid I suppose the person also didn't install apt for security reasons

Comment: Hello, I just found out that username is ROOT. NOT THE ROOT PRIVILLEGE.

Answer (score 0):

Like @terdon I'm suspecting your server is not Ubuntu. (Also, please consider that people reading your questions are not in your context. What's a RA? A research assistant?)

Is the server a physical machine nearby that you happen to access through Putty, some remote machine in a remote datacenter, something else ? Also please run `cat /etc/lsb-release` to get hints.

Regarding root user, some hosting services provide an account that is named root and has somehow more rights that regular account yet is not actually a full superuser. In that case it's somehow logical that sudo is not available.

Regarding `apt-get`, presumably you wanted to use it to install some software. It generally does not exist on non-Debian based platforms.

Chances are, you don't actually need `sudo` or `apt-get` in your context. Those are tools to satisfy needs, what need makes you believe you have to use those tools ?